# iOS program common patterns

Tags: ios

Is there a good tutorial/book/site that addresses general questions about structuring your iOS app code? Common patterns, best practices, etc. Questions like where does one put webservice or database access code, what the best way to do login/authentication, etc.

Thank you

Comment: the experience can give good advices. :D honestly, it depends on the kind of the application what pattern is the best for the current application and for each subparts of the application.

Comment: @holex Experience is good, but when one moves to a new platform waiting for experience to accumulate may not be an option.

Comment: then you should read [this article](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/DesignPatterns.html) for further information. :D this is a very good review of the development on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Cocoa Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321535022). While not specific to iOS programming, it will teach you a lot about patterns used in Cocoa (Touch included) and will probably answer a lot of your questions.